# What happens with a variable declared static in Swift class or struct

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to understand the working of static variable in Swift.

In an object is declared in swift as a static variable when will be the static variable getting initialised.

```
class StaticSample1{  
static let someVariable = "static variable string"  
}
```

If a static variable as following is used

```
class StaticSample2{
static let image1 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
}
```

someimage.png is present in the asset of iOS app.

Will there be memory or performance implication if the image1 is having a large in size. Was wondering if there are more than 1 variable similar to image1, let consider the following

```
class StaticSample3{
    static let image1 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
    static let image2 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
    static let image3 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
    static let image4 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
    static let image5 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
    static let image6 = UIImage(name:"someimage")  
    static let image7 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
    static let image8 = UIImage(name:"someimage")
    static let image9 = UIImage(name:"someimage")   
    static let image10 = UIImage(name:"someimage")      

}
```

Will there be memory or performance of the iOS application be affected.

Also please clarify that the static variable get loaded to the memory only the first time the static variable is used and will remain in the memory till the application quits.

Additionally I would like to understand how is the working  object in swift. Is it same as  that in Objective C.

I would like to understand regarding the working of object/instance created in swift language. Are they still stored in heap and a reference in maintained with stack.

What will be the case of the static variable? Is the static variable stored in stack?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 8):

You've basically created a single global variable named `StaticSample.image1`. There is only one of these variables no matter how many instances you create of `StaticSample`. The variable is initialized the first time the program asks for its value.

Comment: I believe they are initialized in the load phase of an application, what you define is lazy properties.

Comment: 1. what of a class is loaded so that when it's needed it knows where/how to load it? 2. In general what is loaded in the phase of application and what is loaded per request?

Comment: You need to post these as separate questions, not as comments on my answer. Also, I don't understand what you are asking so you should try to explain in greater detail.